# Batch file variable inside if block

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to detect the drive letter that contains removable media (i.e. a memory stick) via `wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL` then I want to use `dir` to get the name of the file on the drive (there should only be one but I don't know what the name is) and pass that filename into `netsh wlan add profile`.

I have this batch file I have written:

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get     caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (
    if %%l equ 2 (
        SET file= | dir %%i /b
        echo %%i\%file%
        netsh wlan add profile filename="%%i\%file%" user=all
    )
)
pause
```

and I expect the output to be `D:\%some file%.xml` but I am only getting `D:`. It seems that the variable `%file%` is not being set correctly.

I've tried many variations but I can't get it to set properly. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: What do you want `file` to set to? actually you are redirecting (piping) the output of `set file= ` into `dir %%i /b`... anyway, you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `file` as you are changing _and_ reading the variable in the same block of code... also you defined only three properties in the `wmic` command line but four `for /F` tokens... finally you are reading `Var` but you never set it...

Comment: What do you mean by _"I've tried many variations [...]"_? wouldn't it be worth to show us at least some of them?

Comment: I have edited the question now to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I do not exactly know what you are trying to accomplish, I decided to provide a modified script in which some issues are fixed. As soon as you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38476496/edit) your question and clarify it I will update my answer accordingly.

So here is the updated code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('
    2^> nul wmic LogicalDisk ^
        WHERE ^(DriveType^=2^) ^
        GET Caption^,Description
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1,*" %%I in ("%%L") do (
        set file=myfile.xml
        echo %%I\!file!
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

- skipped header line from `wmic` by the `skip` option of `for /F`;
- implemented a `WHERE` clause to the `wmic` command line to filter out `DriveType` and so to not need the `if` condition;
- put token `Description` to the last position by removing `DriveType`, so `for /F` token string `*` can be used, as the property value may contain delimiters (spaces) on its own (although `%%J` is not used in the loop then);
- added a second `for /F` loop to remove artefacts from conversion of Unicode output of `wmic` by first `for /F`;
- set variable `file` to a constant value `myfile.xml` just to demonstrate [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (see also `setlocal` command); of course `file` could be set in advance outside of the loop here;
- removed the pipe stuff `SET file= | dir %%i /b` as I have no clue what this is intended to do;

---

#### Update

After the question has been [revised](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38476496/4) and clarified I can provide a solution for the requested task:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('
    2^> nul wmic LogicalDisk WHERE ^(DriveType^=2^) GET Caption
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ("%%L") do (
        for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%%I\"') do (
            set "FILE=%%I\%%F"
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        netsh wlan add profile filename="!FILE!" user=all
        endlocal
    )
)
pause
```

- removed property `Description` from `wmic` command line as it is not used anyway;
- inserted another `for /F` loop to capture the output of `dir /B`;
- the built file path in `FILE` is passed over to `netsh wlan add profile` using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), because this is required when writing and reading a variable in the same block of code; normal expansion would return the value present at the time the *entire* block is parsed by the command interpreter; I enabled delayed expansion inside of the loop structure in order to avoid loss of exclamation marks in the file name, because while reading `for` variables like `%%F`, delayed expansion need to be disabled to not lose such characters;
- actually the interim variable `FILE` and so delayed expansion would not be necessary if you could *guarantee* that there is one file available on each drive; if this is the case, remove the `setlocal` and `endlocal` command lines, move the `netsh` command line into the inner-most `for /F %%F` loop, replace `!FILE!` by `%%I\%%F` and remove the `set` command line;

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have edited the question now.